# What do JW, Evangelicals and Mormons believe about hastening the Return of Jesus?

Tags: prayer, eschatology, lords-prayer, second-coming

I've found some Protestant and Catholic articles about interpreting (Peter 3:12, Revelation 22:20, Matthew 6:9-13, Luke 18:1-8) as the opportunity, for Christians, to hasten the Return of the Lord through prayers.

Are there other interpretation, according to JW, Evangelicals, and Mormons?

Some sources on the matter:

**Among Protestant Etc.**

http://learnbibleprophecy.blogspot.it/2010/12/come-lord-jesus-maranatha.html

http://www.versebyverseministry.org/bible-answers/pray-for-the-end-of-the-world#sthash.GiV7mAO7.7QHYMEE5.dpbs

https://www.oneplace.com/ministries/love-worth-finding/read/articles/can-we-hasten-the-second-coming-of-christ-15204.html

http://www.whatsaiththescripture.com/Timeline/Hastening.Lords.Return.html

http://christianteaching.org.uk/blog/eschatology/hastening-the-return-of-christ/#comment-32538

http://folkslisten.blogspot.it/2010/06/can-i-speed-up-return-of-jesus.html

https://nathanaelflock.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/scriptural-conviction-hastening-the-day-of-the-lord/

http://quailandmanna.com/god-justice/

**Among Catholics:**

From the Catechism:

2817 This petition is "Marana tha," the cry of the Spirit and the Bride: "Come, Lord Jesus."

2818 In the Lord's Prayer, "thy kingdom come" refers primarily to the final coming of the reign of God through Christ's return.88

Comment: This quesiton will undoubtedly be closed because it falls under 'should I do this' or 'is x a sin,' and not a particular denomination's view on whatever it is you are concerned about. These kinds of questions are not allowed in this site. You may wish to edit it so it targets a certain denomination (or even just Protestant or Catholic, more loosely), or ask for what the Biblical case for either side *could* be. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I was asking if it's correct according to any denominational view of the  person who answer

Comment: I can change as "is it correct in your denominational view?", would it be better?

Comment: Not even this would be sufficient, since it stills falls under 'poll' kinds of questions. You should write your question so as to be more 'objective:' "what do Protestants believe about..." or "what do Catholics believe about..." or even more specific. i.e. a question's answers should always be able to help others learn something as to the question asked: which can't be done if it is just an individual's opinion.

Comment: I've heavily edited it according to your suggestions.

Comment: It contains even the precise Scriptures under debate and the results of some researches, let me know if now it's ok

Comment: This seems like it fits the criteria now. However, doesn't Revelation 22:17-21 answer your question? It can't be argued on linguistic grounds (and therefore on no other grounds) that the Holy Spirit and the Church are saying "Come, Lord Jesus. [Amen.]" And doesn't the catechism portion you quoted also answer the Catholic position? (unless you make the Our Father a sin?) In any case, good luck with your question :]

Comment: @SolaGratia I have met many Christians who don't think is a useful prayer, or that is even wrong. Therefore, I'd like to hear a formal discussion from those who don't think it's an useful prayer, or a formal confirmation from those who think it is, like you did now. And I'd also like to hear from other confessions in addition to Protestant and Catholics. Ps weirdly enough, it's hard to find Christian even aware of this, on average

Answer (score 1):

Jehovah's Witnesses have an interesting perspective on this question because they believe the signs of Christ's presence ([Matthew 24:7-14](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/24/#v40024007-v40024014)) are [already visible](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/end-times-prophecy-sign/).

JWs [don't believe](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2003523?q=speed%20up&p=par#h=6) we can literally "speed up" the end of this system of things, because the Father already knows when it will be ([Matthew 24:36](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/40/24#h=197:0-197:117&study=discover)). However, they still pray for God's Kingdom to come. Jesus commanded us to pray for God's Kingdom by including it in the model prayer:

> [**Matthew 6:9-13**](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/40/6#h=46:0-48:0&study=discover) (NWT)
>
> <sup>9</sup> “You must pray, then, this way:
> “‘Our Father in the heavens, let your name be sanctified. <sup>10</sup> **Let your Kingdom come.** Let your will take place, as in heaven, also on earth. <sup>11</sup> Give us today our bread for this day; <sup>12</sup> and forgive us our debts, as we also have forgiven our debtors. <sup>13</sup> And do not bring us into temptation, but deliver us from the wicked one.’

But then, why do JWs pray for God's Kingdom to come? [Here's the answer](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2014728):

> ### Why pray for God’s Kingdom to come?
>
> God’s Kingdom is a heavenly government. Jesus told his followers to pray for it to come because it will restore righteousness and peace to the earth. No human government can completely eliminate violence, injustice, or disease, but God’s Kingdom can and will. God has chosen his Son, Jesus, to be King of the Kingdom. Jehovah has also chosen a group of Jesus’ followers to be associate rulers with Jesus in the Kingdom.—**Read [Luke 11:2;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/42/11#h=108:0-108:111&study=discover) [22:28-30](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/42/22#h=200:0-201:0)**.
>
> Soon, God’s Kingdom will take action against all opposers of God’s rule. So the prayer for God’s Kingdom to come is a request for God’s government to replace all human governments.—**Read [Daniel 7:13, 14;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/27/7#h=96:0-97:0) [Revelation 11:15,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/66/11#h=68:0-69:0&study=discover) [18](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/66/11#h=69:258-70:0&study=discover).**
>
> ### Why will God’s Kingdom benefit people?
>
> Jesus is an ideal King because he is compassionate. As God’s Son, he also has the power to provide help for all who cry to God for aid.—**Read [Psalm 72:8,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/19/72#h=1570:0-1571:0&study=discover) [12-14](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/19/72#h=1575:0-1578:0).**
>
> God’s Kingdom will benefit all who sincerely pray for it to come and who bring their lives into harmony with God’s will. You will never regret learning what the Bible says about God’s Kingdom.—**Read [Luke 18:16, 17;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/42/18#h=163:134-164:0) [John 4:23](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/b/r1/lp-e/nwt/E/2013/43/4#h=25:732-25:928).**

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer about JW on this topic! Very interesting. I find weird that they tie the completely unrelated concepts of not knowing the day with the impossibility of speeding up, I guess they never heard about perspectives like Boethius's omniscence, and that's very fascinating.

Comment: @James The part that's being emphasized in Matt. 24:36 is that God *already knew* the day and the hour at the time Jesus was speaking that verse. Therefore, we can't speed it up because it's already been predetermined.

Comment: Boethius's omniscience explains exactly how it's possible that the day is set, and at the same time prayers have influence (as for any other prayer).

Comment: @James Jehovah's Witnesses have a strong aversion to using philosophy as the basis for their beliefs (especially because many concepts from Greek philosophy contradict what's in the Bible). [Here's an article](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001549) discussing everything JWs believe regarding predestination. They believe God exercises selective foreknowledge, not complete foreknowledge, in order to allow for free will.